# Function change class login-tabs with href

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Im trying to create a link on the first tab  that goes to the register tab of the modal. Right now all i have is two tabs:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="pop-login" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <ul class="login-tabs">
                <li class="active">Login</li>
                <li>Register</li>

            </ul>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></button>

        </div>
```

and the javascript is:

```
/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------ */
/*  LOGIN TABBER
/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------ */
function houzez_tabber(target){
    $(""+target+""+' .login-tabs > li').on('click',function(){
        if($(this).hasClass('active')!=true){
            $('.login-tabs > li').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
            //alert('ok');
            $(""+target+""+' .login-block .tab-pane').removeClass('in active');
            $(""+target+""+' .login-block .tab-pane').eq($(this).index()).addClass('in active');
        }
    });
}
houzez_tabber('.widget');
houzez_tabber('.footer-widget');
houzez_tabber('.modal');
```

Basically I want to create a New to website? Click here to sign up etc... Does anyone know what the url should be in the href??

Comment: add complete HTML and try creating a running snippet

Comment: Hey Muhammad, I tried doing that, still cant work it out. All i need is the correct     <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#active"> - cant work out what it should be. im running https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/modal/#live-demo

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/6k949ogb/1/